# Query to count dates within an array

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB, I need to query a collection to get the count of records each month for the last 6 months. The dates are in an array (sample below), if a document has two dates within the same month, it should only count as one.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2889c8d9651d1d049ea8dd"), 
    "accountId" : ObjectId("5de6ac7f3ab1a29e905ba19f"), 
    "tankId" : ObjectId("5dfbd2635a161648284c4475"), 
    "mostRecentActivity" : ISODate("2020-01-22T19:52:30.771+0000"), 
    "nextScheduledActivity" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "history" : [
        {
            "tankLevel" : 75.0, 
            "locations" : [

            ], 
            "timeStamp" : ISODate("2019-12-22T17:43:36.420+0000"), 
            "fieldActivityDate" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "tankLevel" : 70.0, 
            "locations" : [

            ], 
            "timeStamp" : ISODate("2020-01-22T19:52:30.771+0000"), 
            "fieldActivityDate" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
        }
    ]
}
```

I can query the data to get the total within a date range.

```
db.getCollection("tanksInventory").aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                        accountId: ObjectId("5de6ac7f3ab1a29e905ba19f"),
                        history: {$elemMatch: { timeStamp: {$gt: ISODate("2019-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"), 
                        $lte: ISODate("2019-12-31T00:00:00.000Z") }}}
            }
         },
         {
             $count: "accountId"
         }
    ]
);
```

I've tried to replace the date range using month: in order to get total by month without success.

The output I'm hoping to get is:

```
Month - Count
01        1
02        0
03        5
04        10
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approach technically should work but I choose a simple aggregation to get all the scores at once.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $unwind: "$history"
        },
        {
            $group :{
                _id: {month: {$month: "$history.timeStamp"},  year: {$year: "$history.timeStamp"}},
                count: {$addToSet: "$_id"}
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                year: "$_id.year",
                month: "$_id.month",
                count: {$size: "$count"}
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Notice I added a `year` field as I'm assuming you want to separate same months from different years.